# Good starter WiFi adapter under $30 for experimenting with Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, budget

I am interested in learning how to get into a network and then intercept and modify traffic and am looking to get a WIFI adapter that will let me use the tools in Kali Linux. I have done some research but I am having trouble finding something that has a supported chipset.

I run Kali in a VirtualBox VM running on my Win 10 host. I know the Alfas are great but they are also not in my budget yet.

I have tried a Netgear dongle and I am currently trying one from [TP-link that might not be supported.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/165638/tp-link-archer-t2uh-wifi-adapter)

What do you all suggest? Should I keep the Archer (TP-Link)?

Answer (score 1):

[TP-Link Adapter](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/165660/good-starter-wifi-adapter-under-30-for-experimenting-with-kali-linux) -- NOTE YOU NEED VERSION 1, NOT VERSION 2-- Make sure to check what is being sold. Version 1 has a different chipset that allows scanning, monitor mode, deauth's etc.

[BHIS Wifi travel kit specs:](https://www.blackhillsinfosec.com/?tag=wireless-kit) - in which they show the adapters they use on a regular basis. Usually Alfa Adapters

Take a look at Alfa Adapters.

Comment: The TP-Link I have is V1 but I cannot get it setup in my Kali VM. I will revisit the Alfa models once I have learned some basic tools and need more range.

Comment: @Not_My_Data The problem is probably Virtual Box. They have bad USB interface support for VM's. I would try VMware Workstation. I always have issues with any USB adapter is Virtualbox.